# Information flow for Hololens data visualisation task

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, graph, hololens

I'm currently trying to work with a Microsoft Hololens and I want to basically pull some data from a database, copy it into a form that I can use and then, using Unity, visualize it and have that go into the Hololens.

I have pretty limited coding experience and am looking to improve, but any resources and help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

So my basic understanding of how to go about this task is to:

1. Find the form of the data and put it into a .csv file
2. Draw data from the .csv file and use it to create a graph in Unity. I don't have a graphing asset to hand so if you can recommend one (free if possible!) let me know.
3. Using Unity's ability to display to the Hololens to show this as UI element
4. If this all works I also want to incorporate a system by which the image processing can be used to look at something and therefore generate this graph - I was thinking QR codes or something similar.

Do you guys have any advice, pitfalls and/or resources that could help me?

Thank you!

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow. If you could simplify the problem down we may be able to help you.

Comment: As stated above, it would be helpful to make a specific question, such as loading the data to a .csv file.... if you have code that attempts to do that, perhaps it could be fixed.  I do recommend looking at the MVC/MVVM design patterns however.

Comment: Thanks everyone, appreciate that it was a quite a broad question - thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the questions is very wide.

But, here you can get some points to start:

1. You can get the data (or the file) from a WebAPI or any REST service.
2. You can process as that dataset as you need in Unity.
3. You can search any graph asset in the Unity Asset Store and send the data to it and display in the hololens.
4. You can use the [ZXing](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) library to read the QR code generated to display the graph as well.

Hope this helps.